# Multiple instances of same war on WildFly 10 EAP?

Tags: wildfly, war

I need to deploy a spring-boot REST services application xyz.war on WildFly 10 and need to make it available to 2 different teams. Is there a way I can deploy 2 different instances of same war file but with different context roots?

For example:
app1: /dev/api/myapp
app2: /test/api/myapp

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two options

1. You give every WAR different name and deploy it twice. In this case context root will correspond to WAR name.
2. You tinker with `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` file and set desired `<context-root>` value, see reference: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/appdev/jbossweb.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the same file and affect 2 different runtime names (per default the runtime name is the war name but you can specify it using the jboss-cli or the webconsole).